# Bash: number of children in cron?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

The sample should look if another instance of itself is already running. I do not like a pid-file solution.

Why is n=2 if I start in the console and n=3 if I let cron do it?

```
#!/bin/bash

count ()
{
    ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -v tail | grep $0 | wc -l
}

n=$(count)

echo "`date` n=$n" >> /root/test.log
```

Comment: doesn't your system have `pgrep` ? (not all do), but worth a check for `man pgrep`. Good luck.

Comment: If you leave off the `| wc -l` and just display the ps output, what are the differences?

Comment: none. its with cron an additional line starting with  "/bin/sh -c"

Comment: That explains it. Your cron program runs its commands by doing  `/bin/sh -c "command arg ..."`.

Comment: If you change your crontab line to `exec program args ...`, that may get rid of the extra process.